# Dynamic click events not attaching. .bind()

Tags: jquery

Theres probably a better way of doing this, but I'm trying to remove and then attach click events to the following elements.

```
 $("#clickDiv2").bind('click',showAction2);
 $("#clickDiv3").bind('click',showAction3);
 $("#clickDiv4").bind('click',showAction4);
```

The function works fine, $("#clickDiv").bind('click',showAction); works and it's at the end of the function, but the three I mentioned above do not. Could anyone explain why this might be?

```
$("#clickDiv").click(function showAction(){
     $("#obj1tbl").show();
     $("#obj1tbl").animate({left: "100"});
     $(".goActive").addClass('glow');
     $("#clickDiv2").unbind('click');
     $("#clickDiv3").unbind('click');
     $("#clickDiv4").unbind('click');
     $("#clickDiv").bind('click', function gogo(){
         $("#obj1tbl").animate({left: "999"});
         $("#obj1tbl").hide();
         $(".goActive").removeClass('glow');
         $("#clickDiv").unbind('click');
         $(".dataTableClass").css("opacity", "1");
         $("#clickDiv2").bind('click',showAction2); // DOES NOT WORK
         $("#clickDiv3").bind('click',showAction3); // DOES NOT WORK
         $("#clickDiv4").bind('click',showAction4); // DOES NOT WORK
         $("#clickDiv").bind('click',showAction); //WORKS!!
    });
});
```

Cheers!

And Im restricted to using an older jQuery library, otherwise I would change bind and unbind to on and off.

Comment: Could you show some markup? Also, jQuery's [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is preferred over bind.

Comment: This appears to be a... strange way of doing things. What is the goal here?

Comment: Four buttons, when one is clicked, a div appears on the screen. When it is click again, the div is removed. I want to disable the other div's click functionality when one of them is clicked. And then add it back again... I hope this isnt too confusing

Comment: I don't think you need to unbind anything, just check for the 'glow' class in your click handlers to determine if it is time to do something or not

Comment: Could you show your html?

Comment: It would be best if you could create a fiddle explaining your problem

Comment: I would tend to agree with @Huangism, I generally don't like binding/unbinding events as part of normal operation. However, the solution might be as simple as adding `$("#clickDiv").unbind('click');` in the `showAction` function. Haven't tested that though. A fiddle would be helpful.

Comment: You are binding click on #clickDiv wich is also binding click on the #clickDiv, that is also binding click to the #clickDiv, that will get ungly for each click in that element.

Answer (score 0):

If the element / function exists everything or nothing should work, but not only parts of it...
I need more from your html to  give you any further tips!

Just to mention: bind() is deprecated / removed from jQuery; use .on() instead.
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery website:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call to .bind() occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event delegation in .on() or .delegate().
> Further reading here: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Alternatively, you could simply do this:

```
$("#clickDiv2").click(function(){
    // Your event handler code here
});
```

Comment: From the op's question _"And Im restricted to using an older jQuery library, otherwise I would change bind and unbind to on and off."_

Comment: @PatsyIssa Actually he added that after I had posted the answer plus he doesn't actually say what version he's using. 'Old version' is pretty vague if you ask me. Thank you for your comment though.

Comment: Oh my bad, i ll go back to lurking in the shadows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.on()` for handling events of elements which are not in DOM:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XxRYL/1/)

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="clickDiv2">Click me!</div>
</div>

$(function () {
    $("#container").on('click','#clickDiv2', function () {
        alert("good");
        var myDiv = $("#clickDiv2");   
        myDiv.remove();
        $("#container").append(myDiv);        
    });
});
```

This works with on for further clicks while .click() works for first, because the script modifies the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to remove the click binding of your elements, just assign it once. On the click div test the conditions to make it glow

```
$("#clickDiv2").bind('click',showAction2);
$("#clickDiv3").bind('click',showAction3); 
$("#clickDiv4").bind('click',showAction4); 
$("#clickDiv").bind('click', function (){
     if($(".goActive").hasClass('glow')) {
         $("#obj1tbl").animate({left: "999"});
         $("#obj1tbl").hide();
         $(".goActive").removeClass('glow');
         $(".dataTableClass").css("opacity", "1");
     }
     else
     {
         $("#obj1tbl").show();
         $("#obj1tbl").animate({left: "100"});
         $(".goActive").addClass('glow');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can work out from your question, something like this maybe?

http://jsfiddle.net/xe2X7/4/

```
var $box = $('.box');

$('.button').bind('click', function(e) {
    if($box.is(':visible')) {
        if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $('.button').removeClass('selected');

            $box.hide();
        }
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        $box.show();
    }
});
```